# Dygraph 2.2.1 Add Annotations to graph lines

Tags: javascript, graph, annotations, dygraphs

I have dygraph charts with multiple lines of timeseries data like shown below, I wanted to display a set of annotations on top of the different chart lines where the data has been flagged.

```js
function createGraph(div_element,graph_data) {
const dygraph_div = document.getElementById(div_element);

    gs.push(
      (g = new Dygraph(dygraph_div, await fetchData(graph_data), {
        animatedZooms: true,
        annotations: true,
        zoomCallback: function (minDate, maxDate) {
          let start_date= new Date(minDate).toLocaleString("sv");
          let end_date= new Date(maxDate).toLocaleString("sv");
          console.log("Zoomed to [", start_date, ", ", end_date, "]");
          zoom(begin_date, end_date);
        },
        legend: "always",
      }))
    );

};
```

The function below is used to convert an array containing information of the start and end timestamp where the data was flagged, can be up to 100 elements.

```js
  async function convertToAnnotations(flagged_data) {
    flagged_data.forEach((flag) => {
      const { start_timestamp, stop_timestamp, chart_lines} = flag;
  
      chart_lines.forEach((line) => {
        const graph = gs.find((g) => g && g.attributes_ && g.attributes_.series_ && g.attributes_.series_[line]);
  
        if (graph) {
          const annotations = graph.annotations() || [];
  
          annotations.push({
            series: line,
            x: new Date(start_timestamp).toLocaleString("sv"),
            height: 5,
            width: 5,
            tickHeight: 1,
            shortText: "test",
            text: "Flagged data",
          });
  
          graph.setAnnotations(annotations);
        }
      });
  
    });
    console.log(gs);
  }
```

This is a sample result of one object inside the annotations array at the end:

```
height: 5
series: "A"
shortText: "test"
text: "Flagged data"
tickHeight: 1
width: 5
x: "2022-09-26 13:40:00"
```

My problem is, the annotations have been set in the function and I can see it when I console.log(gs) but nothing is displaying on any charts, the series does match.

I tried to use .getTime() instead of toLocaleString() but I was getting errors.

I tried to manually create html elements but it ended up not working or displaying little circles vertically or in random places, not on the proper chart lines.

I searched everywhere but I could not fix this issue so I came here.